# How to get multiple colors in a cell

Tags: php, laravel, spreadsheet, phpspreadsheet, phpoffice

Currently I'm using PHPOffice library for importing my data from a excel spreadsheet.
My excel spreadsheet is a little special, there is a cell having multiple styles.

I can get styles like font-size, font-weight, etc. But can't get color.

When I import .xlsx file, all color values would be #000000.
When I import .xls file, all color values would be different color values.
For example, #FF0000 -> #00FF00, #00FF00 -> #0000FF, #0000FF -> #000000

Heres my code

```
$inputFileType = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
$reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$spreadsheet = $reader->load($inputFileName);
$cellValue = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A1')->getValue();

if ($cellValue instanceof \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\RichText\RichText) {
    foreach ($cellValue->getRichTextElements() as $richTextElement) {
        var_dump($richTextElement->getText());
        if ($richTextElement->getFont()) {
            var_dump($richTextElement->getFont()->getColor()->getRGB());
            var_dump($richTextElement->getFont()->getBold());
        }
    }
}
```